# Segmentation Fault on return of main function

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault, program-entry-point

I had written a code which is compiling well but is returning a runtime error. n debugging the code I found that the error was in returning from the main function after the return 0 statement.
As far as what I searched I understood that it is a stack buffer overflow problem but was unable to know how it can be corrected.
The code is available here http://ideone.com/7ujF4D

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct box{
    int h;
    int w;
    int l;
};
bool mycomp(const box &b1, const box &b2)
{
    return((b1.l*b1.w)>(b2.l*b2.w));
}
int boxstack(box b[4], int n)
{
    box * all = new box[3*n];
    //box *all = (box *)malloc(sizeof(box));
    int j = 0;
    //cout<<"here";
    int * msh = new int[3*n];
    //int* msh = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    //cout<<"now here";
    for(int i=0; i<3*n; i++)
        {
            all[j].h = b[i].h;
            all[j].w = min(b[i].w,b[i].l);
            all[j].l = max(b[i].w, b[i].l);
            j++;
            all[j].h = b[i].l;
            all[j].w = min(b[i].w,b[i].h);
            all[j].l = max(b[i].w, b[i].h);
            j++;
            all[j].h = b[i].w;
            all[j].w = min(b[i].l,b[i].h);
            all[j].l = max(b[i].l, b[i].h);
            j++;
        }
    sort(b, b+3*n, mycomp);
    for(int i=0; i<3*n; i++)
        {
            int maxh = 0;
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
                {
                    if(all[j].w>all[i].w&&all[j].l >all[i].l)
                        {
                            if(maxh<msh[j])
                                {
                                    maxh = msh[j];
                                }
                        }
                }
            msh[i]=maxh + all[i].h;
        }
    int maxval = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<3*n; i++)
        {
            if(msh[i]>maxval)
                {
                    maxval = msh[i];
                }
        }
    //delete []all;
    //delete []msh;
    cout<<"Here";
    return maxval;
}
int main()
{
    box b[4];
    b[0].h=4;
    b[0].l=6;
    b[0].w=7;
    b[1].h=1;
    b[1].l=2;
    b[1].w=3;
    b[2].h=4;
    b[2].l=5;
    b[2].w=6;
    b[3].h=10;
    b[3].l=12;
    b[3].w=32;
    cout<<boxstack(b,4);
    cout<<"Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code should be first debugged by you. You should first reduce your program to include only **relevant code**. Probably it'll help you to narrow the problem to fewer lines of code (possibly also well indented).

Comment: It usually means you had some pointer-related problem during the program. Use a tool like `valgrind` to debug it.

Comment: Your boxstack function has some major issues. You're using `all` like an array, but you've only allocated memory for one box

Comment: BTW: you alloc space for one box but then you try to use it as vector of 3*n elements...

Comment: You're doing the same thing with `msh`. You only allocate one of them, but use it as an array of `3*n`.

Comment: Why did you comment out the usage of `new[]`?  You made matters worse by introducing `malloc`.

Comment: The problem is still there with use of new[]. I was just trying to check by using malloc and unfortunately posted the wrong code.

Comment: @Archie - Stick with using `new[]` and solve the problem.  Your usage of malloc() is incorrect anyway, while your usage of `new[]` *was* correct.

Comment: @Archie _'and unfortunately posted the wrong code'_ blah, blah. Take care of what you're posting. Drafts will be saved automatically, so there's usually no need to hit the save button prematurely :P ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your loop here:

```
    for(int i=0; i<3*n; i++)
    {
        all[j].h = b[i].h;
        all[j].w = min(b[i].w,b[i].l);
        all[j].l = max(b[i].w, b[i].l);

        j++;  // increment 

        all[j].h = b[i].l;
        all[j].w = min(b[i].w,b[i].h);
        all[j].l = max(b[i].w, b[i].h);

        j++;  // increment again

        all[j].h = b[i].w;
        all[j].w = min(b[i].l,b[i].h);
        all[j].l = max(b[i].l, b[i].h);

        j++;  // increment once again
    }
```

Look at your allocations before the loop:

```
box * all = new box[3*n];
int j = 0;
int * msh = new int[3*n];
```

The `all` has `3*n` items, but your loop not only loops up to `3*n`, but increments `j` 3 times within that loop.  The value of `j` will eventually go beyond the allocated space for `all`.

Comment: The problem was here and also I was able to find the problem which was the use of the wrong array in the sort function call leading to invalid memory access.